# Background image stretches when space is available

Tags: html, css

I am trying to render divs which has a background image css property. The images are fixed size and i want to render them in grid layout. However the divs which has background image stretches when they have space available and i don't that. I am not a css expert so any help would be really appreciated. The html and css are below.

```css
.inner-tile {
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 1em;
      justify-items: center;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(260px, 1fr ));
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
      width: 98%;
      height: 100%;
      padding-top: 1%;
      padding-right: 1%;
      padding-left: 1%;
      /*border: 1px solid red;*/
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .event {
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 5px;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
      justify-items: center;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-radius: 4px;
      min-width: 240px;
      min-height: 200px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .event-image {
      background: url('https://placekitten.com/200/200');
      background-repeat: vertical;
      background-size: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "inner-tile">
        <div class = "event">
          <div class="event-image"></div>
          <h3 class = "learn-more">Corporate Event</h3>
        </div>          
        <div class = "event">
          <div class="event-image"></div>
          <h3 class = "learn-more">Weddings</h3>
        </div>          
        <div class = "event">
          <div class="event-image"></div>
          <h3 class = "learn-more">Party</h3>
        </div>                 
      </div>
```

Comment: I replaced the relative image with a placekitten URL, so we can actually see a background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use percents in `width:` and `height:`, they will take up that percent of the available window space. So, if you have `width: 100%;`, it will always take all the width available in the window (100% of the available width).

If you want it to only take up a few pixels, use `width: 100px;`, which will use 100 pixels no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.event-image {
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pixels instead of percentage if you want fixed width and height for the image, for example:

```
.event-image {
  background: url('https://placekitten.com/200/200');
  background-repeat: vertical;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this kind of issue before, but there is a basic fix in CSS:

```
    .class img 
    {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    }
```

This should work just fine!